# Class member function declaration doubt

Tags: c++, class, function, inline

I'm reading a C++ tutorial and I've ran into this sentence:

> The only difference between defining a class member function
>   completely within its class or to include only the prototype and later
>   its definition, is that in the first case the function will
>   automatically be considered an inline member function by the compiler,
>   while in the second it will be a normal (not-inline) class member
>   function, which in fact supposes no difference in behavior.

I know what an inline function is, my doubt is about which style to choose. Should I define every function inside its class or outside? Perhaps the simplest functions inside and the other outside?
I fear that defining every function inside a class (i.e. having complex inline functions) might mess up the resulting code and introduce debugging problems or weird behaviors during execution. And, finally, there's the "coding style" issue. So,
**which approach is better?**

Thank you :)

Comment: "Better" from what perspective? I tend to worry about the reader / maintainer of the code as the first concern. Performance is a lesser concern unless a profiler says otherwise.

Comment: @David Hammen: that's the "coding style" issue. But right now I'm a hobby programmer, this won't be a problem  for years ;)

Comment: That may well be a problem for you six months from now when can't decipher what you wrote six months ago. Perhaps the most important reader of your own code is your own self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to separate interface and implementation. Interface is your h-file. Put only prototypes there. Implementation goes to cpp-file. This approach has the following advantages:

1. Compilation goes faster because there is no need to compile function bodies several times.
2. Header dependency is simpler because there is no need to include all headers to h-file. Some of the headers are needed only in cpp-file and you can use forward declarations in h-file. Also you can avoid circular dependencies.
3. The last but not the least - it is easier for human beings to understand interface of your class. There is no code mess.

Answer (score 1):

My style: I sometimes will put extremely short (one or two liner) functions in the class itself. Anything longer that I still want as an inlined function go as `inline` qualified implementations after the class definition, and oftentimes in a separate file that the header `#include`s at the end of the class definition.

The rationale for putting an inlined function outside the class is that the implementation of some function usually just gets in the way of a human reader's overall understanding of the class. A twenty line function can usually be summarized in a one line comment -- and that comment is all that is needed when you are reading the class definition. If you need more, go to the function definition, or better yet, Read The Fine Documentation. (Expecting someone to Read The F*** Code is a poor substitute for Fine Documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the part of "Which approach is better?" - From [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html#faq-9.3) -

> There are no simple answers: You have to play with it to see what is best. Do not settle for simplistic answers like, "Never use inline functions" or "Always use inline functions" or "Use inline functions if and only if the function is less than N lines of code." These one-size-fits-all rules may be easy to write down, but they will produce sub-optimal results.

Answer (score 0):

Neither approach is better per se its a matter of preference and style.  Personally I always think that defining the functions explicitly in a seperate .inline file is the best way.  This way you are very explicit over what you do and you keep the header file clean.

Furthermore if you use a macro such as INLINE which is defined as follows:

```
#ifdef DEBUG 
    #define INLINE
#else
    #define INLINE inline
#endif
```

You can then include the inline file from the header in release and from the CPP in debug.  This means that even if the compiler inlines functions in debug you won't have any difficulties when debugging.   Admittedly, though, this isn't such a problem for compilers these days so you may want to skip doing this unless using an old compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a member function which has only one or two statements is probably best with its body written in the class declaration—especially if there are many of them.  A member function with more than 20-50 statements is probably best not in the class declaration.  For lengths and complexities between, it depends on many factors.

For example, having the function body in a class module helps prevent unnecessary recompiling of dependent modules when the class declaration does not change—only a member function body.  This can greatly increase productivity when developing the class.  Once the class is stable, this becomes much less important.